# Android: How to Accumulate a saved int?

Tags: android, save, accumulator

I have an int called coins that is shown whenever the user collects some. It is set to zero whenever the activity is displayed, but I want to show an accumulated result on another page. This is how I've accumulated the result:

```
if (counter == 0) {
    totalCoins += coins;
    counter++;
        }
```

I've displayed the `totalCoins` but whenever the application is killed and resumed, totalCoins is set back to 0. I've tried saving it with Shared Preferences by using the methods

```
private void putValue(String name, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sp.edit();
        prefEditor.putInt(name, value);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }

    private int getValue(String name, int defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", 0);
        return sp.getInt(name, defaultValue);
    }
```

and then used `putValue("TotalCoins", totalCoins);` and `totalCoins = getValue("TotalCoins", 0);` How do I accumulate the amount coins, while setting the coins to 0, and still accumulating it when the activity is restated?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you would to check that if `TotalCoins` is not greater than zero,before set `TotalCoins` to zero ,when Activity is displayed.(probably in `onStart()` or in `onResume()`)